# Is it possible to set column width in Percentage in Vaadin?

Tags: vaadin

Is it possible to set a columnwidth of the Table in vaadin in percentage.If is it possible tell me how to do it with example code snippet.Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 14):

Yes. Use Table.setColumnExpandRatio(columnId, ratio) for that.

Let's say that you got the properties "foo", "bar" and "baz" in your table. If you do this:

```
table.setColumnExpandRatio("foo",1);
table.setColumnExpandRatio("bar",2);
table.setColumnExpandRatio("baz",1);
```

you'll get 25% to foo and baz and 50% to bar